# Help Finishing/Checking Infinity Basis

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

I would greatly appreciate if somebody could check over a proof I have written for a homework assignment. Write now, I feel that some things could be simplified a but, but I'm not quite sure how to do it. The question is as follows:

Let $F$[-1,1] be the set of all functions $f$:[-1,1]$\rightarrow$$R$ Addition is defined as ($f$+$g$)(x) = $f$(x) + $g$(x) and multiplication (a$f$)(x) = a($f$(x)). Assume $F$ is a vector space. Show that $F$ does not have a finite basis.

Attempt:
Assume $F$ has a finite basis, then there exists a finite set of vectors that is linearly independent and a spanning set of $F$. Let $f$,$g$ $\in$ $F$. Since $F$ is a vector space, we know that if a,b$\in$$R$, a($f$(x))$\in$$F$ and b($g$(x))$\in$$F$ and that a($f$(x))+b($g$(x)) $\in$$F$. Since [-1,1] is an infinite set, there are infinitely many a($f$(x))$\in$$F$ and b($g$(x))$\in$$F$ and thus infinitely many a($f$(x))+b($g$(x)) $\in$$F$, which contradicts our assumption that $F$ has a finite spanning set and thus finite basis.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reasoning is not really clear.

As $F[-1,1]$ contains *all* functions, we can consider $f_t$ which satisfies $f_t(t)=1$ and $f_t(s)=0$ for $s\ne t$, for all $t\in [-1,1]$.

Show that all (the continuum) infinitely many $\ f_t$'s are linearly independent.